# Setting remote environment using ssh?

Tags: ssh

How can I ssh into a server and set an environment variable for the remote shell session?  Ideally I'd like to control the name and value of the variable from the origin host.

Answer (score 4):

Use "SendEnv" configuration variable of ssh. see `man ssh_config` for more information.

Comment: Interesting. Never knew about that configuration variable.  Nice to learn something new!

Answer (score 3):

SSH into the machine and then run `export SHELLVAR=value`.  Put that into the `.bashrc` for the account if you want to make it permanent.

Comment: or /etc/profile for a global export.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running a single-shot command on the remote side, something like this may work for you:

```
ssh user@remote "MYVAR=blah the_command -with args"
```

You can string multiple commands together as well:

```
ssh user@remote "export MYVAR=blah; one_command -with args && command2; command3"
```